# Destructor of my class doing wrong? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, destructor, operator-keyword

I have the class `Egg`, where i have predefined constructors. Here is how my operator = and destructor look like:

```
Egg& Egg::operator=(const Egg& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs)
        return *this;

    size = rhs.size;
    name = rhs.name;

    return *this;
}

Egg::~Egg()
{

    size = 0;
    delete[] name;
}
```

And what I want to do is a dynamic array of Eggs, which every time I create a new Egg, it extends. Here's how I do it:

```
Egg* eggArr = NULL;
void createEgg()
{
    Egg * temp = eggArr;
    eggArr = new (std::nothrow) Egg[eggsCnt + 1];

    if (!eggArr)
    {
        std::cerr << "No memory!\n";
        return;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < eggsCnt; ++i)
    {
        eggArr[i] = temp[i];
        std::cout << eggArr[i].getName();
    }



    eggArr[basketCnt].setName(eggsCnt, eggArr);


   eggsCnt++;
   delete[] temp; //problematic line
}
```

If i remove delete[] temp, code works perfectly, but there is a memory leak.
When it stays on the program, for some reason my eggArr is being also destructed, and then when i try to reach some of it's members they are undefined. Is the problem in my destructor, operator=, or somewhere else?

Comment: Think about what `name = rhs.name;` does.  Does this copy the data or just a pointer to the data?

Comment: You're doing a shallow copy instead of a deep copy. Why are you using `char[]` instead of `std::string`?

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem right here:

```
Egg& Egg::operator=(const Egg& rhs)
{
    name = rhs.name;
    ...
}

Egg::~Egg()
{
    ...
    delete[] name;
}
```

After

```
Egg egg1, egg2;
egg1 = egg2;
```

you have `name` as the same value in both `egg1` and `egg2`. When destructors of them are going to be called, it is going to be deleted twice - and this is a straight road to hell.

Here is another example, slightly more complex:

```
Egg egg1;
{
    Egg egg2;
    egg2 = egg1;
}         
std::cout << egg1.getName() << "\n";
```

In this second example, once `egg2` leaves it's scope, `name` get's deleted - and it's the same `name` it shares with `egg1`. As a result, `egg1.getName()` will attempt to use a pointer which was already deleted, and this again is something good programms do not engage with.

You are likely to have the same issue with your copy constructor, and all over your code, and the solution is to stop doing whatever you are doing with your `name` and make it of a proper type - judging by the name, `std::string` seems appropriate.

Comment: Deleting twice is bad, but so is using a pointer that's already been deleted.

Comment: @MarkRansom, sure thing - I was just trying to custom-tailor to the issue OP seems to be having - but you are correct, it's better to highlight this as well.

Comment: @SergeyA so what I understood is that when I use the =, the names point to the same name, and when I delete one, both point to nothing?
I have to make a name with the exact size it is entered, so i want to do it dynamically, unfortunately we haven't learned std::string yet, can u suggest something different? :)

Comment: @user5692938, yes.

Comment: Why can't you use std::string ?

Comment: @Ceros because we are not allowed to use what we haven't studied yet

Comment: Right, I will not say name = rhs.name but strcopy their value instead.
Thank you all :)

Comment: @user5692938, have you learned `strcpy`? If you haven't, than you should just quit that course.

Comment: Yes, we are using <cstring>, learning clases atm, think soon we will start using std::string